# Does EventSource/ETW support more than one language (en-US, es-MX) in a single process?

Tags: etw-eventsource

If I have multiple resource files (one for en-US, another for es-MX etc) in my assembly and I set the CurrentUIThread culture based on my caller, does (or should) EventSource publish the event with culture specific to the thread?

Answer (score 0):

No. Installed manifests can provide multiple languages, but the consumer app chooses which language to display.

Comment: I am not sure you answer addresses my question. I have a micro-service hosted in a service fabric and it is a multi-tenant service. I have multiple resource files in that micro-service. Based on who is calling the micro-service, I need to publish culture specific event from the micro-service. If my service consumer is using en-US culture in header, I should be able to publish en-US specific event using EventSource. If my service consumer is using es-MX culture in header, I should be able to publish es-MX specific event. One micro-service, multi-culture events. Hope that is clear.

Comment: You have created an EventSource manifest with System.Diagnostics.Tracing or System.Diagnostics.Tracing and you have added localised resource files for it and you have installed it, right?

Comment: It is one assembly with both types of resources in the same assembly and I am using following code (from semantic logging block): var listener = new ObservableEventListener();
listener.EnableEvents(ServiceEventSource.Current, EventLevel.Verbose); I also use LocalizationResources attribute on EventSource. I can only make one language work at any given time.

Comment: It appears that EventSource can NOT publish events with strings from different languages based on the client's request from the same service process with the use of multiple resource files.